# Trying to use DirSync on a specific OU in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to use DirSync to get all changes to users in a particular OU (using C#).  From what I've read, the root of the search must be the root of the directory partition, so I'm initializing my DirectoryEntry using the path:

```
string strUserDirPath = "LDAP://xxx.yyy.zzz/DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zzz";
```

and then later I'm trying to set a filter that will give me only users in a specific OU.

The problem is, whenever I try to add the OU to the filter, it filters everything out.  If I say:

```
srch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectcategory=person))";
```

that gives me all users.

The full path to the OU I want is:

```
"OU=aaa,OU=bbb,OU=ccc,OU=ddd,OU=eee,DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zzz"
```

I would like to sync only users that match this complete path.

I have tried adding several things to my filter to do this, but it always ends up filtering out ALL records.  I have tried the following filters to no avail:

```
"(&(objectClass=user)(objectcategory=person)(OU=aaa))"
"(&(objectClass=user)(objectcategory=person)(OU=aaa,OU=bbb,OU=ccc,OU=ddd,OU=eee))"
"(&(objectClass=user)(objectcategory=person)(OU=aaa,OU=bbb,OU=ccc,OU=ddd,OU=eee,DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zzz))"
"(&(objectClass=user)(objectcategory=person)(memberof=OU=aaa,OU=bbb,OU=ccc,OU=ddd,OU=eee,DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zzz))"
"(&(objectClass=user)(objectcategory=person)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=OU=aaa,OU=bbb,OU=ccc,OU=ddd,OU=eee,DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zzz))"
```

I feel like I'm probably missing something very obvious, but can't quite get it.

Can anyone offer any solutions?  As a last resort, I'm thinking of just getting all users, and then programmatically filtering out the ones I don’t need.  Seems clunky, but if it's what I gotta do, I will.

Comment: I ended up doing my "last resort."  Although it's clunky, it works, and for the number of records I'm processing, it still runs quickly.  I'll take it.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible...Please refer the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677626(v=vs.85).aspx)

> "The base of a DirSync search must be the root of a directory
>   partition, which can be a domain partition, the configuration
>   partition, or the schema partition"

Comment: Right.  I acknowledged that in the second sentence of my post.  However, it would seem like there should be a way, after you have bound to the root, to then filter down to the OU you need.  Otherwise, DirSync just isn't very useful if you can't narrow down the results somehow.